# What does "be done" mean in Matthew 6:10 "your will be done on earth as it is in heaven"? E.S.V

Tags: word-study

1. "your will be done" seems not to be a request. e.g. It does not use the word "give" as in "give us this day".
2. Could the Greek be translated "your will is done", Making a statement of fact: God's will is done. After all He is God and if He wills a command to be obeyed He will give sufficient grace that it will be obeyed. Or grace withheld that sin might be found if that is His will.
3. Why is "genetheto" an imperative? Does it have the sense of a command? [Christ in us commanding].
4. As this is the language of prayer maybe the sense is of submission, meaning, "may your will be done". [I agree to it]. But adding the word "may" sounds like adding to Scripture.

   Point 3 appears to me to be central to the other considerations I have mentioned. In summary; Why is "genetheto" an imperative?

Comment: The core question is good and I have up-voted it. But there is a risk of closure by vote due to multiple questions and conjectures. I suggest a stronger focus on one particular aspect : that of the meaning of ως εν ουρανω και επι της γης for which Young's Literal gives  _come to pass as in heaven also on the earth._.

Comment: I have answered your question as it now stands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Γενηθήτω is the aorist imperative passive, 3rd person singular, see [Biblehub](https://biblehub.com/interlinear/matthew/6-10.htm).

> be have done ...

is how I would suggest it should be translated. It is a similar construction to the way in which Hebrew (when looking at God's deeds) views the certainty of the future when God is involved.

It is aorist because it looks into the future and then looks back at the aorist past. 'Be done' expresses an imperative from a future viewpoint. God's will, in the future, will have been done. There is a certainty. Faith believes it.

And faith accords with God's purpose : and obedience yields to it.

The only way God's will shall be done, is if God almighty does it himself. He will do it in a humanity re-born, by a humanity incarnate and resurrected :

> Which were born, not of blood, nor of the will of the flesh, nor of the will of man, but of God. [John 1:13 KJV]

God's will and purpose have been made known in the gospel.

His purpose is eternal :

> According as he hath chosen us in him before the foundation of the world, that we should be holy and without blame before him in love: [Ephesians 1:4 KJV]

God's purpose is clear :

> For it became him, for whom are all things, and by whom are all things, in bringing many sons unto glory, to make the captain of their salvation perfect through sufferings. [Hebrews 2:10 KJV]

God desires to bring many sons to glory, out of the first humanity (from Adam) into another humanity (in Christ). Through redemption and justification and sanctification he shall do it.

Through a humanity come of woman (but not of the first man, Adam) and by sufferings and death that shall perfect that humanity, under the Headship of that humanity, on behalf of the whole of that humanity.

And this to fulfil an eternal purpose :

> Moreover whom he did predestinate, them he also called: and whom he called, them he also justified: and whom he justified, them he also glorified. [Romans 8:30 KJV]

All of this is of God and of God alone, through Jesus Christ.

All that the repentant and believing soul need do, is to obey the voice of Jesus Christ and pray to their Father which is in heaven :

---

το θελημα σου, ως εν

> The will of thee, be have done (be have come to pass, have been accomplished)

ως εν ουρανω

> as in heaven

και επι της γης

> also upon earth.

Amen.

Answer (score 1):

**What does “be done” mean in Matthew 6:10 “your will be done on earth as it is in heaven”? E.S.V**

ΚΑΤΑ ΜΑΤΘΑΙΟΝ 6:10 1881 Westcott-Hort New Testament (WHNU)

> 10 ελθετω η βασιλεια σου γενηθητω το θελημα σου ως εν ουρανω και επι
>   γης

My answer will be based only on let  “your will be done on earth as it is in heaven."

This is  request  and it refers to God taking action to fulfill his will toward the earth and its inhabitants as revealed to us in the scriptures.The person praying is also expressing his own preference for and submission to God's will.

God will express His will by means of his Kingdom in the hands of Christ and the resurrected  **" holy ones."**

Daniel 7:13-14,18  (NET Bible)

> 13 “I was watching in the night visions,  And with the clouds of the
>   sky one like a son of man was approaching. He went up to the Ancient
>   of Days and was escorted before him. 14 To him was given ruling
>   authority, honor, and sovereignty. All peoples, nations, and language
>   groups were serving  him. His authority is eternal and will not pass
>   away. His kingdom will not be destroyed. 18 **The holy ones** of the Most
>   High will receive the kingdom and will take possession of the kingdom
>   forever and ever.’